# Show that the eigenvectors of an orthogonal matrix and its transpose are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, transpose

I know that for an orthogonal matrix $A$, $A^TA = I$, but I'm having trouble using this to show the above. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I forgot to say what I had tried already. Here's my attempt (but the logic might be wrong...) -

$Av = \lambda v$

$\frac{1}{\lambda}Av = v$

$A^Tv = A^T(\frac{1}{\lambda}Av) = \frac{1}{\lambda}A^TAv = \frac{1}{\lambda}v$

Comment: and what bothers you now? Just have a closer look to your last line, you already showed that the eigenvectors are the same, the eigenvalues on the other hand don't need to match

Comment: I guess I'm always just hesitant when it comes to this type of stuff. But if you don't see anything wrong with what I've done, then that's great! :)

Comment: It is fine! But you should definitely use some more structure, equivalences etc...also it might be a good idea to at least mention why the case $\lambda=0$ doesn't matter here

Answer (score 2):

You have $A^T = A^{-1}$. In general, the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are the same (if $A$ is only assumed to be invertible). And it is really easy to see this. Just write down what it means for $x$ to be an eigenvector and apply $A^{-1}$ on both sides.